# How to do mentions in discord bots using python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
if message.content.startswith('Imagine'):
    #Mentioned or not
    if len(message.mentions) == 0:
    #no one is mentioned
    return
pinged_user = message.mentions[0]
await message.channel.send([pinged_user, "got ora ora ora'd and is no longer with us"])
```

[Right now when I try it, it shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aphw0.png)
[I want it to show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA7tc.png)

#Another question, I want it to only happen if you say "Imagine (the person mentioned) living"
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow! This works perfectly, I hope this helps you.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

prefix = "!"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('connected to Discord as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="example"))


@client.command()
async def imagine(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None: return
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} got ora ora ora'd and is no longer with us")

client.run('token')
```

[Example of the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhoDO.png)

Comment: when I try that, the following message pops up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Comment: Nvm, I forgot to add the prefix thing, but it still doesn't work. There is no error message but it doesn't work

Comment: did you forget to add a mention on the end like this: `!imagine @TreeBen77`?

Comment: oh, I fixed this earlier today, thanks for your help :D